# Как найти символ в конце строки?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Проблема заключаеться в том что каждый раз приходит строка с разным количеством символов. Но в конце каждой строки находиться символ "э". Как найти этот символ не зная длины строки ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Функция `slice` может принимать и отрицательное значение, тогда отчет будет идти с конца

```
var text = '134t8t103tu104ti13-э';
var lastChar = text.slice(-1);
```

Ну либо в ручную узнавайте длину строки

```
var text = "1234135134uhkr9u94mэ";
var lastChar = text[text.length -1];
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
    var stringValue = "dfsdfэ";
    var letter = stringValue.split('').splice(-1).join('');
    alert(letter);
```